# Reducing Tensor dimension through Keras

Tags: keras, tensor

I am finding that my model has a tensor that is of shape `(?,1,60)`. I want to know how I can reduce this to `(?,60)`? Not sure whether reshape or Flatten can be done with respect to a dimension. Any help?

Answer (score 3):

Both layers will work, but in this case I prefer using [keras.layers.Flatten](https://keras.io/layers/core/#flatten). Here is an example:

```
from keras.layers import Input, Flatten
from keras.models import Model
import numpy as np

a = Input(shape=(1, 60))
b = Flatten()(a)
model = Model(inputs=a, outputs=b)

model.compile('sgd', 'mse')
pred = model.predict(x=np.ones(shape=(2, 1, 60)))
print(pred.shape)
```